# How would I include additional waypoints on the following GUI

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application

At the moment the **waypoint/via-point** option on my GUI only has room for the *current available waypoint* (in this case Shenley Brook End, which the user can select) and *another waypoint* the user can suggest.

In a case where there were additional waypoints to select (e.g. not only Shenley Brook End but Westcroft, Oxley Park - lets presume that up to 7 additional waypoints can be available... making it 8 in total... not all at once but over a period of time), how could this interface change to accomodate this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have them pile up and push the lower content down. In the screen you provided, has the user tapped 'other' activating the blank field? You could save space by just having a plus + instead of 'other' at the end. To accommodate 7 (max) waypoint containers/buttons you would only need 4 rows:
Waypoint 1 | Waypoint 2
Waypoint 3 | Waypoint 4
Waypoint 5 | Waypoint 6
Waypoint 7 | +

Tapping + could collapse all other 7 and provide user with field instead, when field is complete that would add it to list as a container:

Waypoint 1 | Waypoint 2
Waypoint 3 | Waypoint 4
Waypoint 5 | Waypoint 6
Waypoint 7 | user-added
+

Comment: Is it possible to show me a picture?